# How can I get UWP InkCanvas pixel data?

Tags: uwp, inkcanvas

I need to save the pixel data in my project to an array. I tried to use RenderTargetBitmap but it seems it does not work for UWP. What I have got is stroke data, which contains all the points and their location. What I need is an array that describes which parts are black and which are white in the InkCanvas. How can I make it?

Comment: Did you see this? https://mtaulty.com/2016/02/16/windows-10-uwp-inkcanvas-and-rendertargetbitmap/